# How to make time/date program, shell model of program?

Tags: 11.10, command-line, scripts

I ran in shell：

```
#！ /bin/bash

log=monday

echo "Today is $log"

echo "Today is 'date'"
```

but the result is :
Today is monday
Today is 'date'

How do I make it display the day and date.
Thank you for searching。

Answer (score 3):

The reason why you are echoing the literal string  `date` is because you are using single-quotes.

To ensure that you echo the output of `date` you need to use back-ticks

i.e.

```
echo "Today is `date`"
```

This will output:

```
Today is Sun Apr  8 11:06:37 BST 2012
```